# Concatenating strings with variables with Ruby

Tags: ruby, watir

I am writing a test script that opens a file with a list of URLs without the "www" and "com".

I am trying to read each line and put the line into the URL. I then check to see if it redirects or even exists.

My problem is when I read the line from the file and assign it to a variable. I then do a compare with what's in the URL after loading and what I initially put in there, but it seems to be adding a return after my variable.

Basically it is always saying redirect because it puts "http://www.line\n.com/".

How can I get rid of the "\n"?

```
counter = 1
    file = File.new("Data/activeSites.txt", "r")
        while (line = file.gets)
                puts "#{counter}: #{line}"
                counter = counter + 1
                browser.goto("http://www." + line + ".com/")

if browser.url == "http://www." + line + ".com/"
                    puts "Did not redirect"
                else
                    puts ("Redirected to " + browser.url)
                    #puts ("http://www." + line + ".com/")
                    puts "http://www.#{line}.com/"
                end
```

Basically it is always saying redirect because it puts http://www.line and then return .com/

How can I get rid of the return?

Comment: Your indenting is awful, it makes your code very unpleasant to read. Please use consistent indenting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: `strip`

```
"text\n   ".strip # => "text"
```

Long answer:

Your code isn't very ruby-like and could be refactored.

```
# Using File#each_line, the line will not include the newline character
# Adding with_index will add the current line index as a parameter to the block
File.open("Data/activeSites.txt").each_line.with_index do |line, counter|
  puts "#{counter + 1}: #{line}"

  # You're using this 3 times already, let's make it a variable
  url = "http://#{line}.com"

  browser.goto(url)

  if browser.url == url
    puts "Did not redirect"
  else
    puts ("Redirected to " + browser.url)
    puts url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because your lines are terminated by a newline. You need to `strip` it off:

```
while (line = file.gets)
  line.strip!
  puts "#{counter}: #{line}" 
  # ...
```

Note that there are better ways of iterating over the lines in a file:

```
File.foreach("Data/activeSites.txt") do |line|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code after reindenting it to the "Ruby way":

```
counter = 1
file = File.new("Data/activeSites.txt", "r")
while (line = file.gets)
  puts "#{counter}: #{line}"
  counter = counter + 1
  browser.goto("http://www." + line + ".com/")

  if browser.url == "http://www." + line + ".com/"
    puts "Did not redirect"
  else
    puts ("Redirected to " + browser.url)
    #puts ("http://www." + line + ".com/")
    puts "http://www.#{line}.com/"
  end
```

It's not correct because it's missing a closing `end` for the `while`. But, it's also not dealing with file IO correctly.

This is how I'd write it:

```
File.foreach("Data/activeSites.txt") do |line|
  puts "#{ $. }: #{ line }"

  browser.goto("http://www.#{ line }.com/")

  if browser.url == "http://www.#{ line }.com/"
    puts "Did not redirect"
  else
    puts "Redirected to #{ browser.url }"
    puts "http://www.#{ line }.com/"
  end
end
```

`File.foreach` is a method inherited from IO. If you read the file correctly you don't need to `strip` or `chomp`, because Ruby will handle it correctly when [`IO.foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) reads the line.

Every time IO reads a line it increments the `$.` global, which is short-hand for `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER`. There's no need to keep a counter. Using:

```
require 'english'
```

will enable the verbose names. See [the English docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html) for more information.